# Snowflake table not populated even though pipe is running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm using Snowflake's Kafka connector to get some data into a table. I can see the files in the stage (when I run `LIST @STAGE_NAME;`). According to `SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS`, the pipe is running. Still, I don't see anything in the copy history. However, when I refresh the pipe, I see the table populated in a bit.

Does someone what could be causing this?

Here's the connector configuration in case it helps (nothing special):

```
{
    "buffer.count.records": "2",
    "buffer.flush.time": "10",
    "buffer.size.bytes": "1",
    "input.data.format": "JSON",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "name": "mysnowflakesink",
    "snowflake.database.name": "MY_DB",
    "snowflake.private.key": "abc",
    "snowflake.schema.name": "STREAM_DATA",
    "snowflake.topic2table.map": "customers:CUSTOMERS_TEST",
    "snowflake.url.name": "xyz.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
    "snowflake.user.name": "my_user",
    "tasks.max": "8",
    "topics": "customers",
    "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter"
}
```

Comment: The files are not ingested in real time (when they arrive on the stage). It usually takes a few minutes. If you still don't see the data in the table after a few minutes, I would think you need to open a case with support so they can a look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be my mistake. Namely, I'm using the connector programmatically, and what I didn't do is to call the `preCommit` method. Under the hood, it's making the pipe being used to ingest data.